# Xcode 5 localization issues

Tags: ios, localization, xcode5

Thanks for reading the below (also feel free to be entertained by my frustration)

*//Rant*

First it's obvious this is an issue that there are so many questions for localizing apps. (yes i've started setting aside objects that I can break to make me feel better..haha)

*//To Business*

I've looked everywhere. I've read a number of tutorials for this (started with raywenderlich and have tried a number of different tutorials) and of course I've been searching SO for days.

steps I've taken:

- select project and under localizations add the other language (I've
  read some people select 'use Base Internationalization - i'm not
  using storyboards (lots of nibs) so I don't think that is the option
  I should select)
- Add localizable.strings file to my supporting files selected English
  and 2nd language and I get two strings files. I look in the project
  in finder and I see the two different language folders (in those
  folders are the infoplist and localizable string files.
- I've updated the translation for the 2nd language .strings file ..

After that things get murky on what i'm supposed to do.

- I selected a button that will be in two different languages ( I know
  I should change button titles in code) and clicked the localize
  button and selected the second language. this makes me another set of
  .lproj folders so I have one in the main directory
  (Project/en.lproj)and a second en.lproj in my resources
  directory((Project/res/en.lproj. Is that ok? or should all my assets
  (.strings files, nibs, images) be in only one folder?
- I selected a nib and selected localize > added the 2nd language
  cleaned, built, recleaned, restarted Xcode, deleted simulator files,
  deleted derived data. Built, restarted, cleaned.. broke a few things,
  did it all again.

*//Plea for help*

I've looked at apple docs and they make it seem really easy to do this maybe I'm just missing something really simple. Any advice on what I should do/read/watch/yell would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

james

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//I feel weird answering my own question but I feel like others may find it helpful.

---

**I’m embarrassed to say but the first part of my issue was very simple**.

I figured out what I was doing wrong based on watching “[Localization of your app](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4CkNW2HA7-A)” by Warren Evans. In the video at around 23min he uses some code to get the local and language

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString *language = [locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:{locale localeIdentifier]];
```

My issue was that in project info for localizations I selected to add: French(France) (fr-FR) that created the .lproj folders in my project that were fr-FR.lproj. So when I tested on the device for French it wasn’t grabbing the images or strings.

With the above code I knew it would say French with the local of United States.. bing bing bing!!  Dots were connected.

Originally, I didn’t even notice there was a generic French “French (fr)” option in localizations. I updated my project folder to use French(fr). The strings and the images then displayed correctly when I cleaned, and reset the simulator. *(and yes you can have multiple .lproj files per lang- i have a separate one for resources)*

---

**The second part of my issue was with items not getting updated in the nib files**. The solution which they describe in both apple docs on online seemed to always be missing a step and I was unclear how nibs updated.

It seems the way to do this with storyboards is the best way to keep things dynamic but my project has 15 nibs. The link I found describing that is http://www.ibabbleon.com/iphone_app_localization.html

The above helped me to understand a bit more about using ibtool having already read the apple instructions. The handy Terminal command from that was:

```
find . -name \*.xib | xargs -t -I '{}' ibtool --generate-strings-file '{}'.strings '{}'
```

I used that after changing the directory (cd) in terminal to my project directory and navigated accordingly for the lproj files. *(trying to make this as detailed as I can to help others if they have the same issue)*

To do generate one nib strings file at a time I used apple directions:

```
ibtool --generate-strings-file NIBNAME.strings en.lproj/NIBNAME.xib
```

That created my NIBNAME.strings file for translation.

Once I had the .strings file translated I followed app docs and created a nib from the original English template but with the above translated strings file:

```
ibtool --strings-file fr.lproj/NIBNAME.strings --write fr.lproj/NIBNAME.xib en.lproj/NIBNAME.xib
```

Next I selected the nib and chose ‘localize’ in file inspector then when I selected the nib to check ‘localize language’ it saw that I had already done the above step, which already created a new nib. Xcode asked if I wanted to use it or replace I selected use it and my translation changes were live.
I had to go through the nibs to make sure formatting and centering of buttons looked right but now everything is working.

---

I feel like I should be able to do a master .strings file for all nibs like we do with genstrings based on the answer to this SO question: [How can I extract all localizable strings from all XIB files into one file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743805/how-can-i-extract-all-localizable-strings-from-all-xib-files-into-one-file)

But I’ll need to experiment with that and I think it will be a battle for another day.